# Align 2 textviews horizontally android

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, text-alignment

The screen of my application (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFozp.png)

As seen in the image I have aligned textviews horizontally. When the product name is longer  the name is displayed in 2 lines in the textview. 
But when the number of lines in textview increases the starting lines of two textviews are not horizontally aligned. 
I want the starting lines of textviews to be horizontally aligned. 
Currently I am using LINEAR LAYOUT. Should I change the layout? Can anyone give the code to be written. 
Thus even though 2 textviews are besides each other (as seen in the image) their starting( first line)  should be in same horizontal line.

My code is as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/b22"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout....code

Comment: Hi, Added my layout code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Remove attribute `android:gravity="center|left"` from `LinearLayout`.

**2.** Remove attribute `android:layout_gravity="right|center"` from `textView2` and change its width as `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Product Name -"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Liberty Agile Pension Preserver Product"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

For your design, its best to use a single `RelativeLayout` and put all of your `TextViews` inside it.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Product Name -"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView1"
        android:text="This is Liberty Agile Pension Preserver Product"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Number of Senarios Executed -"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textView3"
        android:text="400"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:maxLines="3"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `LinearLayout` for group of two `TextViews` with `weightSum`. Give weight to both of them out of the sum. Below is an example

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/text_layout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:weightSum="2"
  android:background="@android:color/white">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProductNameLabel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Product Name"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProductName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.4"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```